# how to use exported api endpoint in node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get a better understanding of express and how it uses different end points.

I saw an example of an endpoint which reads in a json file being used like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

export default app => {
  app.get('/api/price', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './price.json'), (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(400, 'ERROR');
      }

      res.send(resp);
    });
  });
};
```

it is then imported in a server.js file like the following. As you can see it is imported as price api.

```
import express from 'express';
import priceApi from './priceapi';
const app = express();

priceApi(app)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on PORT 3000");
});
```

My question is how do I use this priceApi so in particular `priceApi(app)and access the information stored in the JSON file and output information from the JSON file that the endpoint it is referring to in server.js?

Comment: Why do you need to access `./price.json` via express?

Comment: Routes is for HTTP requests . You should use a function instead of a route if you want to load the json file in your javascript

Comment: if you hit the port 3000 you don't get the data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Reading specific parts of `price.json` and return this data through a new endpoint, e.g. `/api/price/details`?

Comment: @eol yes exactly. I am using an example project, which was set up this way. I got confused by `priceApi(app)` in server.js and didn't know how to use it.

Comment: @George_kane when I go to localhost all I get is an `Cannot GET /`

Comment: 1. do you have the node server running?
2. do you go to localhost:3000/api/price?

Comment: @George_kane when I do that it downloads the json file

Comment: try changing res.send(resp); to res.json(resp);

Answer (score 0):

In order to not having to load the file on every request, load the json file once during startup of your app. Then expose a new endpoint and serve the json:

```
import express from 'express';
import priceApi from './priceapi';
const app = express();
const prices = require('./path/to/prices.json');

app.get('/api/price', (req,res) => {
  res.json(prices); // does not necessarily need to be this, you can also map/filter stuff of the prices-json and only return this data
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on PORT 3000");
});
```

Comment: I believe that is what the priceApi is doing. Which is the function export default function.

Comment: No in your code the json file will be downloaded, my code will return the contents of the file as json content-type with the benefit of loading the file just once into memory.